# How to localize text in WPF XAML without embedding the resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to localize a WPF application to support different languages using resource files. I have set the build action for the resource files to "Resource". I managed to do localize strings from the .cs file using Resgen, ResourceManager and GetString() method but I am not able to do it using binding from the XAML file. I also tried Resx extension and static resources in the XAML file but none of them seem to work. I do not want the build action for the resource files to be embedded resources as it has to be compiled again. Could you please suggest me how to localize text from XAML with build action set to "Resource" for the resource files or help me with any other approach so that the resources are not embedded to the application.
Thanks in Advance!!

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btn1" Height="50" Width="150" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=MyResource.World}" />
        <Button Name="btn2" Height="50" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind is:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            string strResourcesPath = "C:\\Program Files\\MyApplication\\MyApplication";
            InitializeComponent();
            CultureManager.UICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            //ResourceManager resourceMgr = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("NewResource", strResourcesPath, null);
            ResourceManager resourceMgr = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("MyResource", strResourcesPath, null);
            string msg = resourceMgr.GetString("Hello");
            btn2.Content = msg;
        }
    }
}
```

LocalizedString.cs:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    class LocalizedStrings
    {
        public LocalizedStrings()
        {
        }
        private static MyApplication.MyResource myresource = new MyApplication.MyResource();
        public MyApplication.MyResource MyResource { get { return myresource; } }
    }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="MyApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:MyApplication" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Could you share with us the XAML code of the file that you're trying to bind to?

Comment: I'm using just a button control to try it on. Thanks!!

Comment: You can edit your post using the "edit" link below the question, and then preface each line with 4 spaces per indentation level. also, we actually prefer that you post CODE, since that allows us to copy-paste it or make easy adjustments.

Comment: One of the benefits of WPF is that you have very little actual code-behind to do for stuff like resources and localization. I don't know for sure how to do it with XAML, but I'm fairly certain there's a way, and that it's easier and more reliable than what you're currently doing in code-behind.

Comment: Actually I have tried that from code behind to localize strings that are dynamic which I would add in the future. For my application I require localization from both code behind and XAML as well.